# Is two teleconverters on a sigma 150-600 sharper than one on a 1100mm mirror lens?

Tags: telephoto, teleconverter, moon, mirror-lens

I was considering taking photos of the moon and stumbled on a review of the MTO 1000a mirror lens. This is acording to this site a sovjet design from the eighties of an 1000mm mirror lens. (Some other sources say 1100mm)

http://allphotolenses.com/lenses/item/c_40.html

I was considering using this with an x2 teleconverter to take pictures of the moon.

Considering the bad reputation mirror lenses have, would I get better results using the Sigma 150-600mm contemporary lens along with 2 x2 teleconverters?

Comment: Which teleconverter(s) are you talking about? They all perform differently.

Comment: Why would you want to use TWO 2x teleconverters on a Sigma 150-600 lens. Using ONE 2x would give you 1200mm. Do you really want 2400mm?

Comment: I was aiming for 1800mm or more. If that is a good idea remains to be seen.

Comment: i think you should rephrase question to be something like: "I want to take photographs of X (moon, bird 200km away, sports person - be detailed). I own this equipment: a,b,c,d,e. Will that be enough? Would buying Z,Y,W help? what is missing?" Right now people are trying to solve problem they don't understand, help them!

Comment: We understand the problem: Someone wants 1800mm+ focal length without spending $10K+.

Comment: aaaaaa: I already stated the goal was pictures of the moon. If I changed to ask if the equipment was enough there would exist no objektive answer. The question I asked should at least be resonably possible to answer objectivly even if both setups are bad.

Comment: @lijat Then perhaps the question should be, "Which is less bad?" It still depends upon exactly *which* Sigma 150-600 (there are currently two different models: Sports and Contemporary), *which* specific 2X TCs, and *which* specific 1100mm mirror lens.

Comment: I specified contemporary in the question, regarding the quality of the teleconverters I do not know. If the answer is heavily affected by it an answer might state both ones that makes the sigma worse and ones that make it better I guess. Or alternativly assume resonably good ones whichever they are.

Answer (score 1):

Teleconverters and lenses tend to have to be somewhat matched to work well. I'd be very surprised if two TCs, aside from giving you a very dark f/25 lens, would give good results; it's simply not a scenario the lens designers had in mind.

If you really, really want that sort of reach for astrophotography (which I admit is beyond my experience) then I'd suggest you're better off getting a smaller sensor camera such as a micro four thirds, and an adaptor to mount it on a telescope.

Answer (score 1):

The mirror lens is f/10 (and M42 screw mount), the Sigma is going to be f/6.3 - double that for each 2x TC.

Mitch [reports his experience](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/57950/37074) using a 1325mm telescope (on an APS-C sensor): the frame is filled, the moon moves out of frame in 10 seconds, and the result is soft; so you want a fast shutter.

The mirror alone will be brighter and likely not as sharp as the Sigma with a quality Teleconverter, which is expected to be sharper but darker.

The mirror has one focal length while the TC will fit all your lenses (doubling your portfolio). I know what I'd buy (the TC) but the mirror is low cost (plus adapter, assuming you don't have an M42 screw mount camera).

With 2 TCs you'll need an equatorial mount to race the moon and keep the shutter open.

It's a question of how many photos of the moon you want and how good you want them to be, for how much money; you can download $1M photos of the moon for free.

If you want photos of all the planets and stars a [telescope](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01IEFJU1C) with a computerized mount will set you back about a thou (depending upon what you want). Enjoy downloading from 10's of thousands of websites while you decide how much time and money to invest, and for what result.